# What do the integer values from TypedArray.getType(int index) correspond to?

Tags: android, c++, xamarin.android, typed-arrays, android-attributes

In android there is a method on the TypedArray object `getType(int index)` which returns an int as described by the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getType(int))

In the documentation and in my research I could not find what the integer that is returned corresponds to.

Does anyone know?

Comment: see `android.util.TypedValue` documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypedArray object `getType(int index)` method Returns the type of attribute at the specified index. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getType(int)

For an example

If we have string as data type in the xml then the int value returned would be 3 if the type of that data is String. ie [TYPE_STRING](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#TYPE_STRING),

and if the data is float then the value returned would be 4 if the type of the data is Float ie [TYPE_FLOAT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#TYPE_FLOAT)

For more details refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html look for the constants starting with prefix TYPE_

Hope it clarifies!!